# How to re-map (i.e.: re-organise) code in Qt-creator?

Tags: ide, qt-creator

In eclipse, I use the keyboard buttons shift + alt + f  to re-organise my code and set the format right. I am wondering if there is an equivalent to this feature in Qt-creator ?

P.S.: I am working on Qt-creator 3.1.2, based on Qt 5.3.1 / OS X El Capitan v 10.11.1

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-A (mark all), Ctrl-I (indent selection).

If you want to indent more than the currently opened file you might want to enable the beautifier plugin in the C++ section. That allows to re-indent all files in the project.

You might want to update your Qt Creator by the way: There were significant improvements done since 3.1 (but not in this area IIRC).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your answer, but it is not the same. It removes only the white-spaces at the beginning of the statements, taking into account each statement type (e.g.: if statement). It doesn't remove unnecessary white-space between words in the statements or unnecessary white-space between statements !!